# pyparsing Optional() & Optional() allows repetitions

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've this simple grammar:

```
word = Word(alphanums + '_')
with_stmt = Suppress('with') + OneOrMore(Group(word('key') + Suppress('=') + word('value')))('overrides')
using_stmt = Suppress('using') + Regex('id-[0-9a-f]{8}')('id')
modifiers = Optional(with_stmt('with_stmt')) & Optional(using_stmt('using_stmt'))
pattern = StringStart() + modifiers + StringEnd()
```

It seems that the `Optional() & Optional()` erroneously allows for multiple repetitions of either `modifier`, and only labels the last one:

```
>>> print dict(pattern.parseString('with foo=bar bing=baz using id-deadbeef using id-feedfeed'))
{
  'with_stmt': (
    [
      (['foo', 'bar'], {'value': [('bar', 1)], 'key': [('foo', 0)]}), 
      (['bing', 'baz'], {'value': [('baz', 1)], 'key': [('bing', 0)]})
    ],
    {'overrides': 
      [(([
        (['foo', 'bar'], {'value': [('bar', 1)], 'key': [('foo', 0)]}),
        (['bing', 'baz'], {'value': [('baz', 1)], 'key': [('bing', 0)]})
      ], {}), 0)]
    }
  ), 
  'overrides': 
    (
      [(['foo', 'bar'], {'value': [('bar', 1)], 'key': [('foo', 0)]}),
      (['bing', 'baz'], {'value': [('baz', 1)], 'key': [('bing', 0)]})], {}
    ),
  'id': (['id-deadbeef', 'id-feedfeed'], {}),
  'using_stmt': (['id-deadbeef', 'id-feedfeed'], {'id': [('id-deadbeef', 0), ('id-feedfeed', 1)]})
}
```

`using_stmt` matches both `id-deadbeef` and `id-feedfeed` instead of throwing an error at `using id-feedfeed`.

Strangely enough, if make the `modifiers` non-optional, then the repitition problem goes away and parsing fails as expected:

```
>>> dict(pattern.parseString('with foo=bar bing=baz using id-deadbeef using id-feedfeed'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 10, in <module>
    print dict(pattern.parseString('with foo=bar bing=baz using id-deadbeef using id-feedfeed'))
  File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1139, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 40), (line:1, col:41)
```

Switching to `+` instead of `&` also causes it to fail as expected. `with_stmt` exhibits the same problem, and making it non-optional also fixes it.

What is it about marking a pattern as optional that allows for repetition inside an `Each()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bug in pyparsing's Each class - will be fixed in 2.0.6.

Comment: Fix has been checked into SVN on SourceSafe

Comment: Do you have an order-of-magnitude sense of how long until 2.0.6 will be released? Or if I want to use the fixed version now, is there a ref that includes the fix and is stable?

Comment: pyparsing's runtime footprint is just the single pyparsing.py file, so you can extract that from SVN at https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/ .  I've already bumped the working version to 2.0.6, and I'll keep a running version date as I apply new updates. Actual release will be sometime between 1 month and 6 months from now (last interval between releases was almost exactly 12 months, and that's too long, plus there's stuff in this release I really would like to get out).